# Perl word count for mulitple files

Tags: perl

I have to display the count of characters, words and lines, and then total them at the bottom of a formatted printf. Somehow when I put in two files to be counted, it only prints out one count. Also it seems like I am just adding the counts together when it should be displaying a separate count for each file then adding them together at the end. I am inputting files from the command console so it would be
perl mywc.pl

This is what I have, Im sure im missing something in my loop but I cant figure out what.

```
#!usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $text_lines = 0;
my $words = 0;
my $chars = 0;
my $counter = 0;
my $total_word = 0;
my $total_char = 0;
my $total_line = 0;

printf ("%-15s", "Files");
printf ("%15s", "Characters");
printf ("%15s", "Words");
printf ("%15s", "Lines\n");

while ($counter < scalar(@ARGV))
{

    open(INPUT, '<', $ARGV[$counter]) or die "Cannot open file!";
    my @doc = <INPUT>;
    foreach my $lines (@doc)
    {
        $text_lines++;
        $chars += length ($lines);
        $words += scalar(split(/\s+/, $lines)); 
    }

    printf ("%-15s", "$ARGV[$counter]");
    printf ("%15s", "$chars");
    printf ("%15s", "$words");
    printf ("%15s", "$text_lines\n");

    $total_word += $words;
    $total_char += $chars;
    $total_line += $text_lines;  
    close INPUT;
    $counter++;
}

printf ("%-15s", "TOTAL");
printf ("%15s", "$total_char");
printf ("%15s", "$total_word");
printf ("%15s", "$total_line\n");

#print "Characters: $chars\n";
#print "Words: $words\n";
#print "Lines: $text_lines\n";
```

Comment: The question is incomplete.Please show your input files and your expected output both.

Answer (score 2):

> *Somehow when I put in two files to be counted, it only prints out one count.*

That's not true.

```
$ script .bashrc .bash_profile
Files               Characters          Words         Lines
.bashrc                   2146            317            89
.bash_profile             3339            502           148
TOTAL                     5485            819           237
```

(Had to fix the shebang path, since it needs to be an absolute path.)

> *Im sure im missing something in my loop but I cant figure out what.*

This, however, is true. Your results are incorrect. The correct counts are as follows:

```
$ wc .bashrc .bash_profile
  89  289 2146 .bashrc
  59  174 1193 .bash_profile
 148  463 3339 total
```

You'll notice the number of lines and chars is correct for the first file, but not for the second file. This is because you forgot to reset the counts for each file.

(Ignore the words, since different definitions of "word" is probably used.)

Move the following lines into your outer loop as they only apply to the file being examined:

```
my $text_lines = 0;
my $words = 0;
my $chars = 0;
```

Comment: Oh good. I thought I was being daft, but it looked like it was working.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to count the no of characters, words and lines in each file passed through command-line.

But the problem with your code is you are declaring all the variables globally, only the total count variables must be global as you need them after processing all the files.The other variables should be declared locally before processing of each file where It should go out of scope after processing of every single file and reinitialized again on the next file.

Second thing `my @doc = <INPUT>` here you are taking the whole file in memory which is not required at all.

I will approach it like below:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings; 

print "No files provided\n" unless(@ARGV);

my ($total_word,$total_char,$total_line)=(0,0,0);
printf ("%-15s", "Files");
printf ("%15s", "Characters");
printf ("%15s", "Words");
printf ("%15s", "Lines\n");

foreach my $file (@ARGV){
       open my $fh, '<', $file or die "unable to open file $file: $!\n";
       #Declare variables separately here for each file
       my($words,$chars,$lines)=(0,0,0); 
       while(my $line=<$fh>){
         $lines++;
         $chars += length ($line);
         $words += scalar(split(/\s+/, $line));
       }
       printf ("%-15s", $file);
       printf ("%15s", $chars);
       printf ("%15s", $words);
       printf ("%15s", "$lines\n");

       $total_word += $words;
       $total_char += $chars;
       $total_line += $lines;

       close $fh;
}
printf ("%-15s", "TOTAL");
printf ("%15s", "$total_char");
printf ("%15s", "$total_word");
printf ("%15s", "$total_line\n");
```

Comment: I think I fixed the last three. First one I am not sure why?

Comment: Exactly, why fail if there are no args? You could simply display zero. (Best would be to read from STDIN, but that's getting out of scope.)

Comment: @ikegami Previously I was thinking why not fail if there are no files? Now I think it is ok. Is it?

Answer (score 0):

I would use Perl's `while (<>) { ... }` construct along with the `$ARGV` variable.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

print "No files provided\n" unless(@ARGV);

my ($total_word,$total_char,$total_line)=(0,0,0);
printf ("%-15s", "Files");
printf ("%15s", "Characters");
printf ("%15s", "Words");
printf ("%15s", "Lines\n");

my %file_counts;
my @files = @ARGV; # Take a copy

while (<>) {
    $file_counts{$ARGV}{lines}++;
    $file_counts{$ARGV}{chars} += length;
    $file_counts{$ARGV}{words} += split;
}

foreach (@files) {
    printf ("%-15s", $_);
    printf ("%15s", $file_counts{$_}{chars});
    printf ("%15s", $file_counts{$_}{words});
    printf ("%15s", "$file_counts{$_}{lines}\n");

    $total_char += $file_counts{$_}{chars};
    $total_word += $file_counts{$_}{words};
    $total_line += $file_counts{$_}{lines};
}

printf ("%-15s", "TOTAL");
printf ("%15s", "$total_char");
printf ("%15s", "$total_word");
printf ("%15s", "$total_line\n");
```